# Image on top of a hotspot

Tags: asp.net, html, imagemap

I am developing an asp.net web application. In which I have an image and two hotspots in that image. I need to add another image in the place of hotspots. I know asp.net imagemap does not support this. But, I need to do this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of surfing over internet, I found answer to my own question.... To do this, set the position of the imagemap as relative.... Place another image (smaller) over the hotspot and set the position as absolute.... As simple as that.... This works fine....

Answer (score 0):

Standard HTML image maps handle pretty much as many "hotspots" as you can put on it. I'm not sure about this whole ASP aspect of it as Im not really into ASP, however this is a client-side issue more than it is a server-side issue unless your generating the hotspots on the fly with ASP.

Look at http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp it gives a very light idea of what I am attempting to talk about. If you have something like Dreamweaver handy you can easily put together an image map. If not theres pleanty of tools to help you do it, as the only pain in the *** about it is the coordinates used to define the spots you speak of. Most tools will let you choose the image, let you draw boxes, circles, or polygons onto it that represent the spots, and then spit out the HTML of it for you to copy/paste into place.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you're asking and I'm not too familiar with ASP, but I don't believe it's server-side (I think it only involves HTML client-side). Am I correct in believing you're asking is whether you can make a certain part of an image a different image and make it [clickable](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp)? What you could do is have the image with those parts of the image copied and pasted onto the clickable areas, unless it needs to be dynamic, in which you can use a [canvas](http://w3schools.com/html5/html5_canvas.asp) or an [SVG](http://w3schools.com/html5/html5_svg.asp).